# ¿Cómo traducir "responsive" al español?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Hace poco oí un par de personas usar las palabras *página responsable* para referirse a lo que en inglés se conoce como "Responsive User Interface" -o *responsive* a secas-.

A mí me parece que esta es una mala traducción de la palabra "responsive". *Responsable* (responsible) no tiene nada que ver con algo que se acomoda automáticamente de una manera óptima de acuerdo a la resolución de la pantalla del dispositivo.

En concreto: ¿cómo traducen ustedes la palabra `responsive` al español?

Yo pensaría que [responsivo](http://dle.rae.es/responsivo) es más apropiado pero quisiera confirmar que es en efecto la traducción más usada en otros países.

Comment: Ajustable es la mejor manera de definir responsive

Comment: En el ámbito técnico, al menos tanto en España como Argentina, se suele usar "responsive", pronunciado en inglés y sin traducir. Esto obviamente no es correcto desde un punto de vista normativo, pero tampoco decimos "cererrón" para CD, como indica la RAE.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Me basaría en la entrada de Wikipedia.

La entrada inglesa para [resposive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) es traducida como [diseño web adaptable o adaptativo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dise%C3%B1o_web_adaptable) en su versión española.

> Interfaz de usuario **adaptable** o **adaptativa**.

Answer (score 9):

Hay tres palabras que se suelen utilizar para traducir *responsive* en relación a las páginas web: adaptable, adaptativo y responsivo.

Creo que *adaptable* es la palabra que suena más natural y parece ser la preferida de la gente en la teoría porque en la práctica se usa poco y se tiende a utilizar la palabra directamente en inglés o *responsivo*.

Yo voy a defender el uso de [responsivo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WCx2AoN) que es una palabra perfectamente válida en español que significa:

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la respuesta.

Es una definición similar a la palabra en inglés y por lo tanto creo que válida.

La razón de preferir el término *responsivo* en lugar de *adaptable* o *adaptativo* es que hay un concepto llamado «adaptive web», que aunque similar no es lo mismo que «responsive web» y para evitar confusiones ([aquí](https://blog.interdominios.com/7-grandes-diferencias-entre-adaptive-web-design-y-responsive-web-design/) un artículo explicando las diferencias) yo veo más lógico traducir *adaptive web* como **web adaptativa** o adaptable y *responsive web* como **web responsiva**.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

En el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll) y el [CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll) tenemos pocas coincidencias para la palabra *responsivo* pero a mi entender los ejemplo del CREA sirven para darnos una idea de que sería factible emplearlo para definir un tipo de diseño web.

Por otra parte veo que ni a la [RAE](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/288942744699809792) ni a [Fundéu BBVA](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/diseno-web-adaptativo-traduccion-de-responsive-web-design-1573/) les gusta *responsivo* aunque difieren en la palabra elegida: la RAE propone *adaptable* mientras que Fundéu prefiere *adaptativo*. Yo me pregunto como traducirían entonces *adaptive web*, ellos dan su opinión de qué palabra se ajusta más al término original en inglés pero yo lo veo desde dentro del sector y quiero diferenciar los conceptos de alguna manera.

Comment: @walen tienes razón, la definición en inglés es diferente pero el ejemplo de *cognitivo* no me convence, yo podría usar otra palabra y decir: "Don Fadrique es una persona _sensitiva_" ¿Por qué una web no puede ser *responsiva* de igual modo?

Comment: He elegido sensitivo porque me parecía similar, igual me equivoco. Otro problema con responsivo es que apenas se ha utilizado, en el CORDE apenas aparece tres veces, en el CREA dos, investigaré un poco más

Answer (score 8):

La traducción que se le ha dado en los distintos grupos de Desarrollo Web en Facebook, Google+, Twitter, etc, es la de Interfaz de Usuario Adaptable  (aunque adaptivo no es correcto, el significado se entiende). Voto por "**Adaptable**".

Answer (score 3):

Traducciones que he visto: Adaptable, adaptivo, reactivo...

Probablemente la que he visto más a menudo es adaptivo, que curiosamente no está aceptada por la RAE y probablemente es una errónea traducción de adaptive, cuya traducción sería adaptativo.

Answer (score 2):

Resposive web design  yo lo explico como diseño web adaptativo o multiresolución o autoajustable. Y hasta la fecha los clientes lo entienden a la primera.

Comment: +1 Autoajustable y multiresolución son muy buenas opciones, en mi opinión. Agregaste dos alternativas novedosas a una pregunta que ya tiene 6 años, muy bien.

Answer (score 1):

Más que una palabra simple, se utilizaría "que responde" o "que responde correcta/adecuadamente".

Comment: Creería que se diría `se responde` en vez de `que responde` a menos que quisieras decir `página que responde`.

Comment: No. "Responsive" es un adjetivo.

Comment: Y siempre que se pueda decir «que [verbo]», se admite la forma adjetival **-nte**: *respondiente* (aunque suena absolutamente *fatal* en este caso)

Answer (score 1):

Yo he usado y he visto que usan **responsivo**.

Como muchas palabras en inglés, sobre todo en tecnología, vamos adaptando la nueva terminología y aunque como dice AlexBcn lo correcto sería diseño adaptable creo que que 'responsivo' acabará por quedarse.

Answer (score 0):

A riesgo de sonar poco común, la palabra ***fexible*** ([DLE/RAE, acepción 4](https://dle.rae.es/?id=I5IQtvP)) indica precisamente la idea de "se puede adaptar al entorno", por lo que *"web flexible"* o *"sitio web flexible"* serían tal vez más apropiados.

[Queja/opinión] Sin embargo, es notorio que en la mayoría de los términos técnicos es más común usar la palabra más parecida al original o a la usada en los ámbitos internacionales que buscar una existente que coincida, tal vez para minimizar las expresiones (Por ejemplo, al admitir el uso de '*acceder*' en lugar del más correcto '*tener acceso a*'.) En ese caso, la probabilidad de adopción de 'responsivo' es alta.

Answer (score -2):

En mi opinión 'responsive', se traduce como 'adecuado'.

Comment: 'Interfaz de usuario adaptable' me parece correcto en este contexto.

Comment: Binevenido a [Spanish.se]. Esta respuesta es tan breve que es casi un comentario. Convendría ampliar un poco, por ejemplo explicando en qué se basa esa opinión, un ejemplo de uso, etc. Echale un vistazo a las secciones [answer] y [help] para entendr un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio y el tipo de respuestas que buscamos.