# ¿Cómo traducir "responsive" al español como atributo personal de quien responde de manera ágil, rápida y eficaz?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

Me gustaría saber cuál es el término que más se ajusta en español al adjetivo inglés *responsive*

He encontrado una pregunta similar:
[¿Cómo traducir "responsive" al español?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5369/17253), pero estoy buscando **otra acepción** de la palabra. Mientras que la pregunta anterior se refiere a un término específico de la web, yo pregunto por un atributo personal, que es una acepción más general:

> En inglés, se dice *responsive* a aquella persona que da una respuesta correcta de manera ágil, rápida y eficaz.

Se trata de un término que se ha puesto de moda por el teletrabajo. Un empleado que contesta rápidamente a los correos electrónicos, por ejemplo, sería más "responsive", que alguien que no mira los correos con frecuencia.

La acepción "responsivo" del DRAE no parece ajustarse a esta definición.

Nota: por si pudiera ser de utilidad, también se utiliza "responsive", en sensores. Un sensor que detecta rápida y eficazmente las variaciones de aquello que está midiendo es un sensor "responsive".

Entonces, ¿cuál sería el término más adecuado en español?

Comment: Mi sugerencia es "receptivo". Una persona receptiva entiende el requerimiento y responde en consecuencia.

Comment: Sí, lo pensé, pero eso es "Que recibe o es capaz de recibir", y no se ajusta demasiado

Comment: Si pensamos en la actitud de la persona, podríamos decir que es diligente, o servicial.

Comment: Hay un problema en el inglés antes de traducir "responsive" al español.  Cuando se usa "responsive" con referencia a una persona,  puede tratarse de una condición médica.  "The EMTs found the victim non responsive".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se me ocurre [***resolutivo***](https://dle.rae.es/resolutivo), que el DLE define como:

> 2. adj. Que intenta resolver, o resuelve, cualquier asunto o problema con eficacia, rapidez y determinación. Necesitamos personas resolutivas.

En este sentido, en un entorno de trabajo yo definiría como resolutivo a aquel al que sé que me resolverá un problema o me conducirá a la persona que sabrá hacerlo.

---

[Gustavson](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14676/gustavson) en los comentarios sugiere también [***expeditivo***](https://dle.rae.es/expeditivo):

> 1. adj. Que actúa o se ocupa de algo con rapidez, sin enredarse en trámites u obstáculos.

Comment: Me gusta más "resoluto" pero no vale la pena ponerlo como respuesta. +1  
`(1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que obra con decisión y firmeza.
2. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que tiene desenvoltura, facilidad y destreza.)`

Comment: Parecido a "resolutivo" podríamos decir "expeditivo".

Comment: @Gustavson me gusta la sugerencia, muy buena. Y me hace ver que coincide su etimología con la de algo que está _expedito_, muy usado aquí. Sobre _expeditivo_, para mí suele tener cierta connotación negativa, como de resolver rápido sin que la calidad sea siempre la máxima (un árbitro que es expeditivo, para mí, sería aquel que expulsa rápido, a la mínima que lo molestan un poco).

Comment: No ha sido fácil elegir la mejor respuesta porque hay varias muy buenas, pero me quedo con ésta porque incluye comentarios muy valiosos (y por la puntuación). La de "expeditivo" es magnífica, ¡Gracias!

Comment: @Gustavson te hago entrega de la mitad de mis 15 puntos por ser la respuesta aceptada, lo de _expeditivo_ gustó :) No sé si valdría la pena darle más exposición poniéndolo en otra respuesta o añadirlo en esta, como te parezca

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Puedes agregarlo a tu respuesta. Gracias por la honestidad, pero no es necesario que compartas el puntaje. Con tu reconocimiento, es más que suficiente. Un saludo cordial.

Answer (score 3):

Justamente hace unos días aplicaron ese término "responsive" a los miembros de nuestra oficina. Cierto es que se está poniendo de moda con el teletrabajo.

Para que destaque más añado esta entrada sugiriendo el adjetivo **diligente**, apuntado por Gustavson en los comentarios.

**[diligente](https://dle.rae.es/diligente)**

> 1. adj. Cuidadoso, exacto y **activo**.
> 2. adj. Pronto, presto, **ligero** en el obrar.

Nótese que **[activo](https://dle.rae.es/activo)** incluye

> 2. adj. Diligente y **eficaz**.
> 3. adj. Que obra prontamente, o produce sin dilación su efecto.

y que **[ligero](https://dle.rae.es/ligero?m=form)**

> 2. adj. **Ágil**, veloz, pronto.

Es decir, las características que indicas de **ágil, rápido y eficaz**, se encuentran representadas en **diligente**.

Answer (score 2):

Una versión que me parece apropiada para el sentido por el que preguntas es `presto`

> [presto](https://dle.rae.es/?formList=form&w=presto#)
>
> Del lat. tardío *praestus.*
>
> 1. adj. Pronto, diligente, ligero en la ejecución de algo.
> 2. adj. Aparejado, pronto, preparado o dispuesto para ejecutar algo o para un fin.
> 3. adv. Luego, al instante, con gran prontitud y brevedad.
>    de presto
> 4. loc. adv. Prontamente, con presteza.

Answer (score 0):

¿Y si en lugar de buscar *una* palabra, usas más? Como en "un sensor de respuesta rápida" cuando en inglés viene como "a responsive sensor". Digo, no todas las palabras en un idioma tienen traducción en otro, por un lado, y por el otro, muchas palabras en inglés tienen definiciones consensuales.

Por ejemplo, tienes la palabra "free". En "sugar-free soda", la traducción literal sería "refresco libre de azúcar", pero es más correcto decir "refresco sin azúcar". Pero la conexión entre "libre" y "sin" es demasiado lejana. Por ende, "responsive" debería tener diferentes palabras que traduzcan el término dependiendo del contexto.

"A responsive interface" queda bien como "una interfaz de respuesta rápida", pero igual quedaría "ágil". En cuanto a usar eficaz, no coincido con las otras opiniones expresadas. Pasar de "adaptive" a "eficaz" es un trecho demasiado largo para saltar con comodidad y, en todo caso, el que la susodicha interfaz sea eficaz o no, es un asunto subjetivo, mientras que ágil no.

---

Hace poco más de cuarenta años que ando en el desarrollo de sistemas y lo que he visto es que cuando un "nuevo" concepto se populariza, se empieza por buscar los términos más adecuados en cada idioma, por un lado, mientras se sigue usando el término en el idioma original, por el otro. Incluso hay compañías que desincentivan traducir los términos que usan (p. ej. Unity es una de esas compañías que rechaza categóricamente traducir Game Object y otros términos usados dentro de su plataforma).

Ahora bien, si lo vemos desde la perspectiva de una empresa que está creando lo que llamo "vaporware", es evidente que quieran emplear términos difíciles de definir por razones obvias y precisamente "responsive technologies" puede adoptar el significado que más te acomode (en otras palabras, el término se "adapta" no a lo que realmente significa, sino a lo que sea que quieras entender).

Octetos por bytes, sí... ¿Pero cuartetos por nibbles? Incluso en español tenemos diferencias culturales que requieren términos distintos para un mismo significado: ordenador, computador y computadora, o ficheros y archivos, entre muchos otros. En este sentido, forzamos el significado de la palabra para que se adapte al uso que le damos. Quienes hablan inglés de forma nativa saben que pueden ampliar o reducir los alcances de una palabra a voluntad, pero eso ya es harina de otro costal.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Creo que en el caso de la interfaz se usa otro significado: responsive en el sentido de que se adapta inmediatamente al usuario. No sería el mismo caso aquí, que buscamos algo como "rápido en responder"

Comment: Claro que, como dices, podría usar más de una palabra. Es lo que he estado haciendo. Claro, la pregunta es si existe algún término que lo sintetice directamente, pero puede que no exista, por supuesto.

Answer (score 0):

"Listo" se podría aplicar a quien tiene las calidades que mencionaste.

Comment: Esta respuesta aparece ahora mismo en la cola de revisión como "low quality". Deberías explicar un poco mejor porqué crees que ese adjetivo es una buena traducción para "responsive" en este contexto (un enlace al DLE, citar la definición y compararla con la dada para responsive?)

Comment: Perdoneme la falta de calidad. En las regiones que conozco de habla española (México por mayor parte) se usa "listo" tan ampliamente y con tan ancha aplicación para varios grados de aprobacion o elogio a personas con las calidades como "ágil", rápida y "eficaz" que me pareció supérfluo definirlo o citar definiciónes. Busqué "listo" después en DLE y se encuentran sinónimos, como "diligente, pronto, expedito," y "dispuesto para hacer algo" entre otras. ¿Es posible que no se usa tanto de este modo en otros lugares? ¿O sea que es demasiado familiar y el contexto exige más formalidad?

Comment: A cada uno de nosotros nos gusta o ayuda recibir críticas o [feedback](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13606/5481) de manera determinada. Yo hice ese comentario intentando ayudarte a entender el problema de que el sistema marcaba  el post (debido a su corta longitud). Entiendo que para ti esa respuesta es muy obvia, pero date cuenta de que algunos visitantes o no son hispanoparlantes nativos o son de regiones distintas. Intenta tener en cuenta en tus respuestas a aquellos usuarios para los que no va a ser tan obvio lo que estás explicando.

Comment: Gracias, Diego. Entendido.